Estimating KL Divergence from Multiple Independent Samples
I'm working with two discrete probability distributions, (P) and (Q), and exploring different ways to measure the divergence between them using Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence. Specifically, I'm looking at two scenarios:

Single Sample from (Q):
The KL divergence can be expressed through an expectation with a single sampling from (Q):
$$ - E_{i\sim Q}[\log(\frac{P_i}{Q_i})] = KL (Q\|P) $$
This formula uses the expected value of the logarithmic ratio of probabilities from (P) and (Q), sampled according to (Q).

Multiple Independent Samples from (Q):
When sampling independently (M) times from (Q) to get a sample set (J_M), the expression becomes:
$$ - E_{J_M}[\log( \frac{1}{M}\sum_{n \in J_M} \frac{P_n}{Q_n})] $$
Here, the average of the ratios (\frac{P_n}{Q_n}) is taken over the sample set, and then the logarithm of this average is considered.


My question is: Can the second expression provide a meaningful estimate of the KL divergence? If so, how would this estimation relate to the standard KL divergence calculated from a single sample?
I'm particularly interested in understanding whether the averaging process in the multi-sample scenario affects the estimation accuracy and whether there's a known relationship or approximation that links these two expressions.
Any insights, references, or suggestions for further reading would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
